# Transferring Individual games between 3dses

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-network-id

Okay y'all, I have a problem.

In late April, I decided to buy the Nintendo "New" 3ds, upgrading from a 2ds. When I had bought the N3ds, I had decided to give the 2ds to my brother.

You see, the 2ds had several downloaded things on it: 5-6 themes, The Legend of Zelda Ocarina of Time 3D, Pokemon X, Mario and Donkey Kong: Minis on the Move, several virtual console games, and on a separate SD card, I had TLOZ: Triforce Heroes, and New Super Mario Bros 2.

My brother told me that he mainly only wanted POKEMON X, and a few 3ds themes, and said I should transfer the rest of the stuff over to the new 3ds (which I was planning on doing anyways). At the time, I was fine with it, as I had assumed that the transfer would be like the DSI-3ds transfer, which allowed you to transfer certain games.

Upon looking into getting a transfer done, I discovered that I could only do a transfer of EVERYTHING, which would completely clear the original system.

So is there a way around this, or did I just pretty much throw a lot of money down the drain by getting the NEW 3DS?

Comment: Yes, a system-transfer transfers everything from a console to another. That's due to the NNID, because downloaded contents are tied to your account. This means that, if you'd leave a game on your 2DS (with some kind of workaround) you won't be able to play it because a different NNID is not allowed to play it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of right now, there is sadly no system to transfer individual pieces of software between multiple 3DS. The only possible way I could think that you could accomplish this desired transfer is maybe through the "[PC-Based Transfer](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14169/p/430/session/L3RpbWUvMTQ3NDA2ODY0Mi9zaWQvU3ZERjFQLW0%3D#gs=eyJndWlkZUlEIjoxNDMsInF1ZXN0aW9uSUQiOjE5LCJyZXNwb25zZUlEIjozMiwiZ3VpZGVTZXNzaW9uIjoiLTRXTDFQLW0iLCJzZXNzaW9uSUQiOiJTdkRGMVAtbSJ9)," however, I have not attempted this so I do not know if this method would allow for any means of selective transference.

Barring that, you could always try talking with Nintendo Support [1 (800) 255-3700] and see if you could work out something there.